# Is there a restriction on the number of thread queues in a multithreaded C application?

Tags: multithreading, push, pull

I work at NASA, and I am working on a multithreaded C application that decompresses, demosaics, and displays video images from satellites. I inherited this application, and as part of getting the app to process images quickly enough, one of the changes I made was to add threads to do different tasks, so a thread that worked only in RAM would not have to wait for a disk write to complete. I increased the number of threads in the app from six to eight, and one of the new threads never pulls from its queue, even though I did the PUSH and PULL calls( which use xmitter and receiver) the same as the other threads. The other new thread I wrote works fine. I have tried everything I can think of to get the one thread to pull off of its queue, but nothing works, and eventually the queue fills up and transmissions to my app are blocked. I appreciate any help I can get with this problem.

I tried writing the new thread the same as the other threads, and I thought that was enough. However, the new thread never pulls off of its queue.

Comment: The number of thread queues cannot be the problem since it fills up. Look at your thread locking scheme related to the receiver associated with the queue. Is it looking at the correct lock(s)?

Comment: Eight is a minuscule number of threads. There are servers out there that run hundreds of thousands of them.

Comment: I have removed all the locks on the queues. I should add that the thread in question starts up correctly, it just never pulls anything off of its queue. I am using ZMQ_PULL and ZMA_PUSH to send queue items between threads.

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify. I removed locks on the queues before I posted the original question.

Comment: I have fixed the problem with not dequeuing on certain threads. My problem now is a very strange one. The image processing run is processing the images correctly and then then sending them to the display image run. The test I am running has over 2000 images from four different cameras, with the images displayed on four different screens. The images are all processed without any problems for all four cameras, but the display of the images from the second camera are never displayed, and in fact are never dequeued by the display image run. Switching screens for the second camera does not help.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by having the ZMQ PULL bind to the socket.